# Python/Django UnicodeDecodeError 'ascii' codec can't decode

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8

I got views.py:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
def myview(request):
    object = MyObject.objects.get(id = 1)
    testvar = u"test %s" % object.myfield
```

And I got error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /myurl
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Unicode error hint
The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: J������
```

J������  - myfield value
In database this field is utf8_bin.
In model this field is CharField

```
sys.getfilesystemencoding() #-  UTF-8
sys.getdefaultencoding() #- ascii
sys.getdefaultencoding() #- ascii
locale.getdefaultlocale() #- ('en_US', 'UTF-8')
locale.getlocale() #- (None, None)
```

Python 2.7.6
Django 1.5.8

I tried also:

```
object.myfield.decode("utf8")
```

And got error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /myurl
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 6-10: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have administration side of this object - and everything works perfect, even with utf-8 symbols.

And if I print out type of object.myfield, then i get:

```
<type 'str'>
```

Comment: I don't know about the first bit of your question, but the last bit where you get a "can't *en*code" while attempting to *de*code a value happens in Python 2.x when you try to decode a unicode string: Python will encode it first (with the ascii codec) so that it can attempt to decode it. That says to me your field is already unicode so the main problem probably isn't in the lines you showed us but elsewhere when something tries to encode the unicode value to ascii.

Comment: Is `myfield` a foreign key? If it is, can you post [__str__() and __unicode__()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/#choosing-between-str-and-unicode) of related model?

Comment: Duncan, my code throws first error till decode() part - in this part "u"test %s" % object.myfield"

Comment: danhip, no it is not ForeignKey, just CharField

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
def myview(request):
    object = MyObject.objects.get(id = 1)
    testvar = u"test %s" % object.myfield.**decode('utf-8')**
```

Comment: To make this a great answer, please explain what this does